# IIS and Load-Balancing

Tags: asp.net, wcf, http, iis, load-balancing

If I want to load-balance my WCF services, the standard advice is to [disable HTTP persistent connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128(v=vs.110).aspx).  In other words, ensure that "Keep-Alive" is not active.

This is fine if I want each and every request properly balanced, and if I don't mind the small increase in latency required to re-create a connection on every call.

However, in my case I actually want to avoid the additional latency - and I don't mind if repititious requests through the balancer are "sticky" to one server.  Instead I simply want the ability to remove one of the servers from the balanced group, and allow connections to gracefully transition to the other servers.

To achieve this, I need some way for "Keep-Alive" to be de-activated while requests are still in-flight.  It would be great to use a WCF message-inspector that, when signalled, adds a "Connection: close" header to replies.  Unfortunately, [explicitly adding "connection: close"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb8c9628-6a4a-4f0f-be19-174de8900913/sending-connectionclose-from-a-wcf-service-hosted-on-windows-service-wininet?forum=wcf) is perhaps not possible.

So my next option is to adjust IIS configuration.  While my application is still handling in-flight requests, I would adjust settings in the "Http Response Headers" of the pertinent web site.  In there it is possible to ["Set Common Headers" and turn "Keep-Alive" off](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Enable-HTTP-Keep-alive-in-IIS-7-75.aspx).

Fantastic, except for one thing: changing any configuration causes the app domain with my application to unload.  IIS is kind enough to allow existing in-flight connections to bleed-off gracefully when I do this, and the next in-bound request causes the app domain to load again.  All subsequent processing will now have "Connection: close" sent in the replies.

Thus no in-bound requests were harmed by making the config change, but I may violate my SLA for request processing because of the time it took to re-load the app domain.

In short, I just want some way to de-activate HTTP persistant connections - without causing the app domain to unload and reload.

I would be glad to have a custom WCF message inspector take care of this, if someone could explain how to overcome the "override" behavior that IIS enforces on the "Connection" HTTP header.